# AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key' error in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-1.5, django-managers

I am using Django `'1.5c1'`. I have this line in my settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'fileupload.galaxyuser'
```

Here's my `Galaxyuser` model:

```
class GalaxyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

I want to authenticate from Galaxyuser model. However when I login I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** `Traceback:`

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/zurelsoft/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/backend.py" in login_backend
  26.         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  59.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  16.             user = UserModel.objects.get_by_natural_key(username)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login_backend/
Exception Value: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

Comment: can you provide your settings.py file

Comment: paste the track back also

Comment: django will create id for you no need to add id in your model and if you are using the django user model then username must be OneToOne field for the User model check the docs

Comment: The only thing I want to do is authenticate from the GalaxyUser model using the build in Django authentication function. I am getting error while doing do. Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have created a new user model but you have not yet specified a manager for that model. If you're not yet familiar with managers in Django I suggest reading the [documentation on that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/) first. As the Django 1.5 say ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/)):

> You should also define a custom manager for your User model. If your User model defines username and email fields the same as Django's default User, you can just install Django's UserManager; however, if your User model defines different fields, you will need to define a custom manager that extends BaseUserManager providing two additional methods: `create_user()` and `create_superuser()`.

In short, if your model uses the same username and email fields as Django's `User` model then you can write:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class GalaxyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

Alternatively, you'll need to subclass `BaseUserManager` (also in `django.contrib.auth.models`) and implement the desired methods. Then, you'll need to assign it to the `objects` variable for your model.

Comment: I am getting this error after implementing this:
type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Comment: I have renamed my model to User from GalaxyUser.

Comment: I read the documentation you provided but I couldn't find the solution. Can you help me on this?

Comment: I have solved this using: USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' but I get another error: 'User' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Comment: I think you can solve that by extending your user model from `AbstractBaseUser`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser

Comment: Did like this: class User(AbstractBaseUser) but got another error: FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractBaseUser'

Comment: Since I want to authenticate from another table I don't want to subclass AbstractBaseUser.

Comment: some pretty unhelpful comments here - if we've landed here, then we're not understanding the docs.

Comment: The link to the managers docs is outdated; here is the (2020) new version: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/`

Answer (score 5):

for me..
I had forgotten to add `Parentheses` end of manager..

```
objects = UserManager

objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: My problem was I didn't even have "objects = Usermanager()" or any variation of it. Adding this close to the bottom of the class and making sure to use "from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager" solved it for me. This answer helped me notice it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `UserManger` class for your `GalaxyUser` class, make sure you add `objects = UserManager()` to that

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a user manager for the custom model. Maybe `GalaxyUserManager`. Then add `objects = GalaxyUserManager()` to your user model

Comment: Oh, you save my day. Thank you a lot)