# Django 1.10 Legacy Database - Unable to Retrieve Objects

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a very small (so far) legacy database which I auto-generate in Django using

`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

I put this in my python package that holds the app and added to my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

I ran: `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`

> Migrations for 'app_name':
>     app_name/migrations/0002_auto_20180809_0453.py

Next: `python manage.py migrate app_name`

> Operations to perform:
>     Apply all migrations: app_name
>   Running migrations:
>     Applying app_name.0001_initial... OK
>     Applying app_name.0002_auto_20180809_0453... OK

I checked that the models were created using: `python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001`, which showed that several models were created.

My `models.py` file looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Test(models.Model):
    date = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    shift = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    timer = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    target_produce = models.FloatField(blank=True, 
null=True)
    actual_produce = models.FloatField(blank=True, 
null=True)
    oee = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Test'
```

I am trying to access my database from `views.py`. Here is my code:

```
File: views.py                              

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from lineoee.models import Test

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
        context = {}

        lines = Test.objects.date() # <-- Error here
        print(lines)
        return render(request, 
       'lineoee/index.html',context)
```

I get the atribute error

> 'Manager' object has no attribute 'date'

I tried to implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723099/attributeerror-manager-object-has-no-attribute-get-by-natural-key-error-in) and added the `UserManager` import and `objects = UserManager()` but I ended up with

> 'Usermanager' object has no attribute 'date'

Any suggestions on how I can eliminate this error and access data from my legacy database correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it as,

```
Test.objects.all().values('date')
```

If you need to print respective data,

```
for i in Test.objects.all().values('date'):
    print i['date']
```

or

```
for i in Test.objects.all().values_list('date', flat=True):
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. So the print statement below should in turn otuput the respective data?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my error. How can I access a particular value of 'date', since various methods and the answer below still result in errors. Thanks!

Comment: When I do as you suggested to print all the dates I get no error, but when I try to print only the most recent date I get No Attribute Error as above. It must be how I querying. This results in an error: `lines[0].date`

Comment: @fcp can you please post full query you are trying to execute ?

Comment: I am trying `last_oee = Test.objects.latest('oee')` with error: `no such column: Test.id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177710/discussion-between-nishant-nawarkhede-and-fcp).

Answer (score 0):

An "objects" object is not the data itself. As Django tells you, it is a manager which allows you to access the data. In order to get data from it you should use one of its methods: get() for a single data entry, all() or filter() or exclude() for a list of entries. E.g.

```
lines = Lineoee1.objects.all()   # retrieves all data from Lineoee1 model
lines[0].date                    # retrieves date field from the first entry
```

Or if you want to get only dates, then try to use values_list() method with list of field names:

```
dates = Lineoee1.objects.values_list('id', 'date')
```

Added 'id' as an extra field to identify which entry does dates belong to - you may remove or replace it with whatever primary key you have.

More info on querying at [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: I still get an error: `no such column: LineOEE1.id` when I run `dates = Lineoee1.objects.values_list('id', 'date')`