# line 158, in get_app_config return self.app_configs[app_label] KeyError: 'account'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am developing a django project, the main directory/project name is `django-basic-ecommerce`.

One of the apps name is `accounts` (note that it has the final "s").

as I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/my/path/basic-django-ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 158, in get_app_config    
    return self.app_configs[app_label]    
KeyError: 'account'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[...]
/my/path/basic-django-ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 165, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'account'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

[...]   
/my/path/basic-django-ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 176, in get_user_model
raise ImproperlyConfigured(django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'account.User' that has not been installed
```

The last message makes me think that I missed some configurations for `account.User`, however, it is correctly installed in `mainapp_ecommerce/settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'accounts',
...
'django.contrib.auth',
...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User' 
# it changes the builtin model user to User custom defined model
```

and about that `AUTH_USER_MODEL` , it refers to the account.User modeldefined in `accounts/models.py` as

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # is h* allowed to login?
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user, not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # superuser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    # email and password are required

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager
```

So, what could be the problem here?

Comment: your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is `account.User`, not `accounts.`. Typo in the question or irl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @willeM_Van Onsem, it turns out that

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'account.User' that has not been installed
```

because it's not `account`, but `accounts`.

So I substituted

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
```

with

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

Also, in class `User`,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # is h* allowed to login?
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user, not superuser
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # superuser
```

this line is referring to a non-existing field `username`

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

So I turned the line into

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Furthermore, as indicated [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75206984/7658051), I have changed

```
objects = UserManager
```

to

```
objects = UserManager()
```

otherwise one would get the error

```
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).get_by_natural_key(
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

Then I have run `python manage.py makemigrations`, manually inserted a default value `timezone.now` when asked by django

```
It is impossible to add the field 'timestamp' with 'auto_now_add=True' to user without providing a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.

 1) Provide a one-off default now which will be set on all existing rows
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value as valid Python.
Accept the default 'timezone.now' by pressing 'Enter' or provide another value.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
[default: timezone.now] >>> timezone.now
```

so that the migration went fine

```
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts/migrations/0004_user_timestamp_profile.py
    - Add field timestamp to user
    - Create model Profile
```

and in the end I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```